# Which is the better book to learn MongoDB ?

Tags: mongodb

The Definitive Guide to MongoDB, Third Edition

OR  MongoDB in Action, Second Edition

or anyother ?

Answer (score 0):

I think The Definitive Guide to MongoDB will guide the mongoDB to use it effectively for Big Data things, in the other hand the MongoDB in Action book will covers wide range of usage and not sticked to one path . As well as it will cover more practicals than the definitions . Choose Wisely !!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are good number of options available in the market for you to get started with MongoDB but you must choose it wisely. Rather than going for a physical book I would suggest to go for a online course which is quite convenient to learn at your own pace and as per your convenience.

All what I learned in MongoDB if from ~ [Projects in MongoDB - Learn MongoDB Building Projects](https://www.udemy.com/projects-in-mongodb/?couponCode=SEPDS10)

Hope you love it too.